# TemplateProcessingException when trying to load simple Thymeleaf form

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm really struggling to get my head around this - I keep getting the following error when I try to load the main page of my Spring Boot application:
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 15, col 28)

The point at the line in question is `th:field="*{name}"` in `index.html` below - as per suggestions in a lot of other posts, I've passed a new Respondent object to the model in the GET request, but I can't even get the form page to render... What am I missing?

**index.html**

```html
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"/>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:replace="fragments.html :: header"></div>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/respondent}" method="post" th:object="${respondent}">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"><br/>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{groupname}"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>

    <div th:replace="fragments.html :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**RestController.java**

```java
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    private RespondentRepository respondentRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getHome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("respondent", new Respondent());
        System.out.println("added respondent");
        return "index";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("respondent")
    public Respondent newRespondent() {
        return new Respondent();
    }

    @PostMapping("/respondent")
    public String newRespondent(@ModelAttribute("respondent") Respondent respondent, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("respondent", respondent);
        System.out.println("adding to repo (hopefully)");
        respondentRepository.save(respondent);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**Respondent.java**

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Respondent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String groupName;

    public Respondent(String name, String groupName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public Respondent(Long id, String name, String groupName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public Respondent() {
    }

}
```

**RespondentRepository.java**

```java
public abstract class RespondentRepository implements CrudRepository {}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
2022-09-14 19:12:03.905 ERROR 14852 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-6] Exception processing template "index": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 15, col 28)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 15, col 28)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1404) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1148) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1087) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:166) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:237) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'respondent' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    ... 105 common frames omitted

2022-09-14 19:12:03.913 ERROR 14852 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 15, col 28)] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'respondent' available as request attribute
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Sorry, added now!

Comment: I actually think the error is the next line. Try changing "*{groupname}" to "*{groupName}". The getter for group name is getGroupName().

Comment: @LeeGreiner I've checked and it's definitely happening on the line with 'name' rather than 'groupname'... In any case, I've tried correcting that and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7  As far as I understand it I'm already doing what's suggested there, ie passing a new object in the GET request that the form can then map to and pass back in the POST request. Or am I misunderstanding how this system works?

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 There's already one explicitly defined in the Respondent class, but I've also tried it with declaring it Lombok and it didn't make a difference

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 there's barely anything to it so far, so I haven't put it up on github or anything

Comment: Ah well, if you do, I'd be glad to try and help. Also, why is your repo an abstract class? And why don't you pass a type to the generic class CrudRepository instead of using a raw type?

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 Ah! That'd be because I misremembered what I did in my previous project that actually worked... I remembered it being an abstract class that implemented the CrudRepository interface, but I've just checked and it was actually an interface extending the CrudRepository class...

Comment: Indeed. Try extending `CrudRepository<Respondent, Long>` instead. Always avoid using generic types raw. You also don't need to pass a name to `@ModelAttribute` if the param name is the same. And if you make your `RespondentRepository` final you don't need to annotate it with `@Autowired`

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 I've chucked the project up on a private repo on github - may I send you an invite to take a look?

Comment: Sure, feel free, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

### ComponentScan

Looking into your project I found this annoation:

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.educity.educitymanager.Domain")
```

What this does is turn off the default componentscan that is built in `@SpringBootApplication`. By default, the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation will scan for components in the hierarchy of the map it is in. So, it will find every bean that is on the same level or below.

Since you set it to only scan the Domain package, which only contains models, and thus not any beans, like your `SecurityConfiguration` or your `RestController` (which isn't really a REST controller btw). Nothing you write in those classes will do anything if the beans aren't found & created by Spring.

So, just *remove the annotation and you should be fine*.

#### Some More Tips

Try avoiding added complexity when building out your domain. Try to build your domain without security / external database (use in memory h2 instead for example). You will also not have to copy/paste the password / login every time you restart the application. This will make it easier to pinpoint problems. Also, don't add anything to your project without understanding what it does first. I know this is rather hard when starting to explore Spring, but minding these rules will help you to not get stuck early on.